# Scala file cannot be edited in Scala-IDE

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I am trying to implement a micro-service in Scala and I decided to use Scala-IDE as editor as advised.
My S.O is Ubuntu 14.04 64, and I am using java 1.7 and Scala-IDE version downloaded [here](http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html).
I created a project using [this tutorial](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Tutorial), however I can't edit within the Scala editor the file just created (like there was a lock on the file itself).
[image]

Please notice that my project has already Scala nature.
Please advise how to solve this issue.

Comment: attach screenshot maybe?

Comment: I added the screenshot, however I don't think it will be of any help...simply the newly created helloWorld.scala file is not editable. Cheers.

Comment: If you do a right click on the file and then select `Properties > Resource` does it tell you that the file is read only?

Comment: @sschaef I don't think that would matter, would it? Even if the file was read only Eclipse should allow him to edit but not save, I think?

Comment: That's the first thing that I checked and permissions are ok, moreover since the file is created by the same user and in the IDE there's no reason why such user wouldn't have the permissions set as sschaef suggested.

Comment: @AR1 you might want to consider using intellij community edition with the scala plugin